# Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to trigger a JavaScript function when I'm clicking on a button,
but nothing happens the only error message I could figure out was in the JavaScript-console :

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list    vacAdmin:204
```

This is my function, I don't even have a 204th line, I also checked the argument list :

```
function editRecord(idVac, title, location, reference, duration, buisness, task, commencement, interest, contractType, salary, func, requirements, employmenttype, employmentlevel){

    var vacform = document.createElement("form");
    vacform.setAttribute("name", "form");
    vacform.setAttribute("method", "post");
    vacform.setAttribute("action", "/vacChangeBox");

    var vacancyId = document.createElement("input");
    vacancyId.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
    vacancyId.setAttribute("name", "vacancyId");
    vacancyId.setAttribute("value", idVac);
    var titleform = document.createElement("input");
    titleform.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
    titleform.setAttribute("name", "title");
    titleform.setAttribute("value", title);

    var locationform = document.createElement("input");
    locationform.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
    locationform.setAttribute("name", "location");
    locationform.setAttribute("value", location);

    var referenceform = document.createElement("input");
    referenceform.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
    referenceform.setAttribute("name", "reference");
    referenceform.setAttribute("value", reference);

    var durationform = document.createElement("input");
    durationform.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
    durationform.setAttribute("name", "duration");
    durationform.setAttribute("value", duration);

    var buisnessform = document.createElement("input");
    buisnessform.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
    buisnessform.setAttribute("name", "buisness");
    buisnessform.setAttribute("value", buisness);

    var taskform = document.createElement("input");
    taskform.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
    taskform.setAttribute("name", "task");
    taskform.setAttribute("value", task);

    var commencementform = document.createElement("input");
    commencementform.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
    commencementform.setAttribute("name", "comencement");
    commencementform.setAttribute("value", commencement);

    var interestform = document.createElement("input");
    interestform.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
    interestform.setAttribute("name", "interest");
    interestform.setAttribute("value", interest);

    var contractform = document.createElement("input");
    contractform.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
    contractform.setAttribute("name", "contractType");
    contractform.setAttribute("value", contractType);

    var salaryform = document.createElement("input");
    salaryform.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
    salaryform.setAttribute("name", "salary");
    salaryform.setAttribute("value", salary);

    var funcform = document.createElement("input");
    funcform.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
    funcform.setAttribute("name", "func");
    funcform.setAttribute("value", func);

    var requirementsform = document.createElement("input");
    requirementsform.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
    requirementsform.setAttribute("name", "requirements");
    requirementsform.setAttribute("value", requirements);

    var employmenttypeform = document.createElement("input");
    employmenttypeform.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
    employmenttypeform.setAttribute("name", "employmenttype");
    employmenttypeform.setAttribute("value", employmenttype);

    var employmentlevelform = document.createElement("input");
    employmentlevelform.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
    employmentlevelform.setAttribute("name", "employmentlevel");
    employmentlevelform.setAttribute("value", employmentlevel);


    vacform.appendChild(vacancyId);
    vacform.appendChild(titleform);
    vacform.appendChild(locationform);
    vacform.appendChild(referenceform);
    vacform.appendChild(durationform);
    vacform.appendChild(buisnessform)
    vacform.appendChild(taskform);
    vacform.appendChild(commencementform);
    vacform.appendChild(interestform);
    vacform.appendChild(contractform);
    vacform.appendChild(salaryform);
    vacform.appendChild(funcform);
    vacform.appendChild(requirementsform);
    vacform.appendChild(employmenttypeform);
    vacform.appendChild(employmentlevelform);
    vacform.appendChild(vacancyId);

    var csrf = document.createElement("input");
    csrf.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
    csrf.setAttribute("name", "${_csrf.parameterName}");
    csrf.setAttribute("value", "${_csrf.token}");
    //append crsf
    //apepend element
    vacform.appendChild(csrf);


    document.body.appendChild(vacform);
    //submit form
    vacform.submit();



}
```

The function get triggered by this button :

```
<td><input data-vacIdEdit="${vac.id}" type="button" name="Bearbeiten" value="Edit" onclick="editRecord(${vac.getId()},${vac.getTitel()},${vac.getLocation()},${vac.getReferenceCode()},${vac.getDuration()},${vac.getBuisnessTravel()},${vac.getTasks()},${vac.getCommencement()},${vac.getInterestGroup()},${vac.getContractType()},${vac.getSalary()},${vac.getFunctionality()},${vac.getRequirements()},${vac.getEmploymentType()},${vac.getEmploymentLevel()});"></td>
```

Comment: do not mix JS with HTML..... these errors get hard to debug.... http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript

Comment: Why do you `setAttribute("value", ...)` multiple times in a row? You *are* aware that it always overwrites the previous value? Did you try using your browser's debugger with "break on errors" enabled? There isn't enough information to diagnose the problem remotely.

Comment: Note that you called your form element `vacform`, but one of the lines refers to "`form`": `document.body.appendChild(form);`. Again, it's impossible to say if it's relevant as your problem is not reproducible.

Comment: I thought I could append multiple attributes to a from, isn't that possible ? Yea thanks for the `vacform` mistake

Comment: A form can have multiple child <input> element, but aby HTML element can have just one value. This is not related to this question, however; you were supposed to investigate which line your debugger stopped on.

Comment: Got it it throws the error at the button : ` <td><input data-vacIdEdit="3" type="button" name="Bearbeiten" value="Edit" onclick="editRecord(3,Technischer Zeichner,Bielefeld,133XYZ,1 Jahr,keine,Erarbeitung von technischen Zeichnungen,01.01.2016,TraineeProgramm,Ausbildung,3000?,Entwicklung,Abitur,Trainee,Vollzeit);"></td>` it just stops there Edit: Tried to put the line into a code block but it doesn't work sorry

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79187/discussion-between-datprettyurkel-and-kryger).

Answer (score -1):

I explored the code on JS Fiddle and for some reason it appears that the editRecord function is causing the problem. The console states that the function is not defined when you click the function. Still not sure why this is happening, but I hope finding the problem helped you.
Here is the js fiddle I used to work on the problem.
 [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Mikey013/tf73v34y/)

```
<td><input data-vacIdEdit="${vac.id}" type="button" name="Bearbeiten" value="Edit" onclick="console.log(editRecord)"></td>
```

Running this code returns an error saying that editRecord is undefined, showing that the editRecord function is not being transferred to the HTML.

Comment: This is a red herring, behaviour you introduced yourself by porting the snippet to JSFiddle. This service does some magical sandboxing to allow custom code execution, so the `editRecord` function is not really global, as it would be in a normal environment.

Answer (score -1):

its simple..

```
<button onclick="editRecord(&apos;${vac.getEmploymentType()} &apos;)">Click me</button>
```

Comment: Please explain your answer a bit more: try to expand on it